# Image transform in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, image-transforms

How can I trigger an image transform in a Craft plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

It essentially works just like it does in twig...you just call `getURL` with the valid name of a transform

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$criteria->id = 1;
$asset = $criteria->first();

if ($asset)
{
    $url = $asset->getUrl('myTransform');
}

$imgUrl = $image->getUrl('tranformHandle);
```

...as I understand it that triggers the  image to be transformed on-demand if the transform does not already exist.

Comment: Hum this is what I did but it does not work. I have a problem ok I will try to see in the logs.

Comment: OK I found it : got a problem with my permissions on the directory...

Comment: Glad you got it working.